# What is the purpose of leading slash in HTML URLs?

Tags: html, url, links

I have noticed that some blogs posts have links using a value starting with `/` in the `href`.

For example:

```
<a href="/somedir/somepage.html">My Page</a>
```

Does the leading `/` mean the path is starting from the site root?

In other words, if the site URL is `www.mysite.com`, the effective `href` value is `www.mysite.com/somedir/somepage.html`?

Is this a convention accepted in all browsers?

Comment: You may also find a double slash url, `//somedomain.com/somedir/` in some links, which uses the same protocol used for the current page, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978235/absolute-urls-omitting-the-protocol-scheme-in-order-to-preserve-the-one-of-the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's important to start a URL with a `/` so that the intended URL is returned instead of its parent or child.

Let's say if your browsing `/cream-cakes/` then you have a link on the page that has `blah.html` without the forward slash it is going to attempt to visit page `/cream-cakes/blah.html` while with the forward slash it'll assume you mean the top level which will be `domain.com/blah.html`.

Generally, it's best to always use `/` in my experience as its more friendly when you change the structure of your site, though there is no right or wrong assuming that the intended page gets returned.

Answer (score 17):

> Does the leading '/' mean the path is starting from the site root?

Technically this is referenced in section [4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4) of [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) as an "absolute-path reference":

> A relative reference that begins with a single slash character is
> termed an absolute-path reference.

It ensures the path is absolute to the root directory and not the current directory (termed a "relative-path" reference). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613274/why-would-a-developer-place-a-forward-slash-at-the-start-of-each-relative-path) for an expanded discussion on that.

Comment: Can you address the browser support for this type of link?

Comment: @Stephen every browser ever made since at least 1998.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Probably way earlier than that. In fact, I'd go on a limb and just say "every browser _ever_"; that syntax has been part of the URL standard from the very beginning.

Answer (score 4):

That's a root-relative link. It's a relative link (somewhat akin to `../`) but it begins at the root of the site. If a page three levels deep on the site begins a link with the forward slash, the remainder of the path will be relative to the root of the site.

A benefit to this form of pathing is fewer characters in the markup:

`http://example.com/page.html`

vs

`/page.html`

Another advantage is portability across domain changes. If `example.com` content is moved to `example.org`, for example, root-relative links will still work, assuming the same directory naming/layout is used. Especially useful if developing pages locally, then uploading to the web.

As with other types of pathing - relative (`../`) and absolute (`http://...`) this is still subject to updating links when files or directories are renamed or moved.

Comment: It can also break links during domain changes. For example, if `blog.example.org` moves to `example.org/blog/`. If The links had been `https://blog.example.org/foo`, they'd be easy to redirect, but `/foo` links introduce a lot more complexity to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) indicates that the answer to my question is yes.

The effective `href` value is indeed: `www.mysite.com/somedir/somepage.html`.