# Image path for multilingual site? Can I use same image file without rewriting every URL?

Tags: images, multilingual, path

Suppose I wanted my website to have

`www.aaa.com/bbbb
www.aaa.com/th/bbbb`

The first one is the default language while second one is in Thai. I think I should prepared my folder structure like this :

`root
 -bbbb
 --index.html
 --images
 -th
 --bbbb
 ---index.html`

Now that I copied the `index.html` file from `/bbbb`folder into `/th/bbbb` folder and finished translate it, I realized that all path for images like in `<img src=` or `url(...` of CSS has been broken because I did not copied the whole `bbbb/images` folder with it.

Instead of rewriting every url to go back one step and look for images in `/bbbb` folder (that is, prefix every URL with `../bbbb/`)  is there more practical way? Because the translated page uses nearly identical images with original ones.

Also for the solution presented, would that impact the SEO of images in any way?

Comment: Check http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a more practical way. Use relative paths everywhere. Instead of setting your image path to `src='www.aaa.com/images/myimage.jpg'`, set it to `src='/images/myimage.jpg'` instead.

Using relative path has no impact on SEO. It is neutral.

Comment: By relative path did you mean absolute path? I just realized that all of my URLs was like `images/myimage.jpg` (relative path from current file) instead of `/images/myimage.jpg` (absolute path from root). Adding a single slash now let me copied the file to anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: No, an absolue path is with the domain name (www.aaa.com). What you had is a relative path to the current directory. With a leading '/', it is a relative path to the root. Cheers!